# how to install hrbrmisc in R

Tags: r, github

I am a beginner in R, I want the below library hrbrmstr/hrbrmisc for one of my programs.

I have installed Devtools and then tried to install using 
install_github("hrbrmstr/hrbrmisc")

It gives an error as **Error: could not find function "install_github"**

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: All together, `install.packages("devtools") ; devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/hrbrmisc")` (or run `library(devtools)` instead of `devtools::`).

Comment: Yes, it did not work. Zheyuan Li

Comment: I got the following error when I tried to run it as you advised @ alistaire                                                                                                                                                                                                             devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/hrbrmisc")
Downloading GitHub repo hrbrmstr/hrbrmisc@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/hrbrmstr/hrbrmisc/zipball/master
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Couldn't connect to server

Comment: That indicates your Internet was down or GitHub was.

Answer (score 0):

Just run:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/hrbrmisc")
```

to install the package.